# can i have 2 apks of same application one in prod and one in alpha channel simultaneously

Tags: android, developer-console

I have an android application. Its already released to play store . So its in production state as shown in google developer console.
Now i added a new feature (In app purchase) , But before i release the app with this new feature , i want to test it .

So i need to upload my apk to alpha channel . I want to know that if i upload a new apk to alpha will it cause any changes to my apk in production.
I want the apk in production to be working as it is and still want to test the new apk with in app purchases in alpha channel . Is that possible?

Comment: See this link to get some information https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that will work fine. Just make sure your new APK bumps the version code so the play store sees it as a new version.

Comment: you mean my version code for alpha should be greater than the one which is in production ?

Comment: Yes. The version code is chosen by you and any update to the app (even when pushing in for a new alpha or beta) needs to be a value the system will see as greater than the previous one (s) See here for more information on the version code: .https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html